# Run manticore return 'Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack' error

Tags: solidity, compiler

I compile my project just fine but when I run manticore for my solidity file, it return Stack too deep error. I did some research but none of which I found work. Here is the config I'm setting:

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.4",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
            details: {
              yul: true
            }
          },
          viaIR : false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks

Comment: It's possible that manticore has to run the code with different optimizations (none possibly). Does your code compile if you disable it? In any case, try following this guide https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep

Comment: I disabled the optimizer and it didn't work.